# glTF accessor.max/min validation

Tags: gltf

The KhronosGroup [glTF 2.0 specification](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/2.0) requires that *accessor.max* and *accessor.min* bounds be specified for POSITION arrays. However, these values must be expressed as text strings, whereas the the vertex position coordinates are stored as single-precision floats in base64-encoded strings.

The problem I am experiencing is that the online [Khronos glTF validator](http://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/) and the Microsoft Visual Code extension (which is presumably a port of the Khronos validator) compares these values to 15 decimal places (i.e., double precision) and reports an error if they do not match exactly. This makes it exceedingly difficult to debug large glTF files, as it results in tens of thousands of errors.

More important, I am wondering whether these errors are important. I could modify my glTF file generator such that the vertex position coordinates can be expressed as text strings without error, but it seems like a ridiculous solution. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to file an issue on the validator or the VSCode extension; it's probably something that should be handled in one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

The VSCode extension [uses](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-vscode/blob/1ff32cfca3beddb30002856f22b9e3e9e1b65015/package.json#L300) the actual Khronos glTF Validator, not a port, via the npm package.  The validator is written in Dart transpiled to JavaScript, and VSCode itself is based on Electron and TypeScript, and can and does run JavaScript as part of its extensions.

The author of the validator talks about mix/max precision in this issue:

https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Validator/issues/79

> The validator expects that numbers stored in JSON match those stored in buffers when they are treated with the same precision (IEEE single-precision for floats).

He then gives an example for the Ruby language that the OP there was asking about.

If the explanation there doesn't match with what you're seeing, please [file a new issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Validator/issues/new) with the validator.  Thanks!